# What is the big modified Mon Calamari cruiser in RotJ?

Tags: star-wars, return-of-the-jedi

It looks like a standard, but seems to have fins extending out and is the first thing hit by the 2nd Death Star. It appeared to be holding a small freighter/cruiser similar to a GR-75 transport, when the fly-under was done by the camera.

[image: A Mon Calamari MC80 cruiser in Return of the Jedi]

Comment: A time hack would be nice.

Comment: Some time before the DS-2 fires it’s main gun during the battle of Endor. Watched it with family so I couldn’t pause it, sorry

Comment: Are you thinking of [this shot](https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/b/b8/Dsiipown1.png/revision/latest?cb=20130417042841)?

Comment: Or [this one](https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/5/54/Liberty.png/revision/latest?cb=20130417043224) just before it's Death Starred?

Comment: @Cadence, yes, that’s the ship.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing the screencap into the question body, feel free to make further edits if you would like.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In that scene you are actually seeing different models of Mon Cal vessels. The two main capital ships used by the Alliance are the MC80 and MC80A cruisers. The one with fins is the older "Liberty" type, which were pleasure cruisers converted for military use by the Rebellion.

[image]

More information about both ship models can be found at the links below:

- [MC80 "Liberty" Type Heavy Star Cruiser](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/MC80_Liberty_Type_Heavy_Star_Cruiser)
- [MC80A "Home One" Type Heavy Star Cruiser](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/MC80A_Home_One_Type_Heavy_Star_Cruiser)

Comment: In one of the continuity... *things* for which Star Wars is so justifiably known, the exact relationship between the Liberty and Home One types changes from source to source, but I think the current Canon is that the MC80 and MC80A are contemporaries (or at least they show up in all the same events). In Legends, *Home One* itself was an MC80 but with one-off modifications; when the Rebels started building more along the same lines they designated them MC80a.

Comment: Further confusing the issue is that MC80s are supposed to show variation in design and size from one ship to the other (because they were cruise liners and exploration ships, not mass-produced warships) but this is rarely if ever depicted, because it's easier for the props department/animators to make several copies of the same one or two ships instead. Under the original Mon Cal scheme, both of these variations are simply MC80.

Comment: @Cadence - I'm mostly just familiar with Legends continuity, but you're right there. The Mon Cal pride themselves on sculpting each ship individually, with no two ships being 100% the same. The others were converted "cruise ship" models), but "Home One" was heavily modified during its construction to be an actual warship, which is why Admiral Ackbar used it as his personal flagship. The entire line got the same type of modifications, which is where the MC80A model came from.